# JOOQ: How to map a record to an aliased table (from a nested query)

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a nested query with a join and I'm trying to map the results back to a table. The query is similar to this:

```java
var nested = context.select(BUSINESS.fields()).from(BUSINESS).limit(size).offset(size * page);
var idField = nested.field(BUSINESS.UIDBUSINESSID);

var result = context.select(nested.fields()).select(BUSINESSALIAS.fields())
.select(BUSINESSCONTACT.fields()).select(BUSINESSIDENTIFIER.fields())
.select(SITEADDRESS.fields()).select(WEBSITE.fields())
.from(nested)
.leftJoin(BUSINESSALIAS)
.on(idField.eq(BUSINESSALIAS.BUSINESSID))
.leftJoin(BUSINESSCONTACT)
.on(idField.eq(BUSINESSCONTACT.BUSINESSID))
.leftJoin(BUSINESSIDENTIFIER)
.on(idField.eq(BUSINESSIDENTIFIER.BUSINESSID))
.leftJoin(SITEADDRESS)
.on(idField.eq(SITEADDRESS.BUSINESSID))
.leftJoin(WEBSITE)
.on(idField.eq(WEBSITE.BUSINESSID))
.fetch();
```

Mapping the results back to the `BUSINESS` like this `record.into(BUSINESS).into(Business.class)` causes a large number of exceptions because there are ambiguous matches for some fields. 
The actual error is:

`Ambiguous match found for BusinessId. Both "alias_34775958"."BusinessId" and "MCDH"."dbo"."SiteAddress"."BusinessId" match`

How to I tell JOOQ that the `BUSINESS` table qualifier should be the alias `alias_34775958` when mapping the record into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `record.into(BUSINESS)` causes this ambiguity, because your query doesn't really have any columns from the `BUSINESS` table (despite your using this table in a derived table).

Try using `record.into(nested.fields())` instead, which will produce the exact field references including the generated alias. Alternatively, you can also use a table with an explicit alias:

```java
var nested = table(select(BUSINESS.fields())
                   .from(BUSINESS)
                   .limit(size)
                   .offset(size * page)).as("b");
```

And now, that `nested` is of type `Table<?>` instead of `Select<?>`, you can use it directly in your `record.into(nested)` call.

Comment: This works but it would be great if there were some way to update the alias in the Result so that I could pass the Record to a generic record processor. I have some code that maps the record into POJOs that I have to special case when the result is coming from a query with a nested query. Something like `result.realias("oldAlias", "newAlias")` or `result.realias("oldAlias", BUSINESS)`

Comment: @EliPulsifer: That's an interesting idea. I wonder if it wouldn't be better to fix the alias in the source query instead rather than patching the result. If you think this is an idea worth pursuing, feel free to create a feature request here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new